# Confirmation before deleting from an ArrayList (Android)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, confirmation

I've set up OnContextItemSelected to show an alert when the user tries to delete an item and asks them for confirmation. The problem being that the "confirmationReceived" variable is getting set to true the first time the code is executed with nothing else happening, then when it's executed a second time the item is deleted before the user has a chance to confirm that they want it deleted.

onCreateContextMenu

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Timetable Item");
    menu.add(0, Remove_Item, Menu.NONE, R.string.Remove_Item);
}
```

onContextItemSelected

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    AlertDialog diaBox = AskRemoveConfirm();
    diaBox.show();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case (Remove_Item): {

            if(confirmationReceived == true) {
                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;
                menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                int index = menuInfo.position;
                removeItem(index);
                confirmationReceived = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

AskRemoveConfirm()

```
    private AlertDialog AskRemoveConfirm()
{
    AlertDialog myRemovalDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Confirmation")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
            .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    confirmationReceived = true;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .create();
    return myRemovalDialogBox;
}
```

Comment: do the remove task in the positive button click... just before dialog.dismiss()

Answer (score 0):

do somthing like this

```
   private AlertDialog AskRemoveConfirm()
    {
AlertDialog myRemovalDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Confirmation")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
        .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                confirmationReceived = true;
               if(confirmationReceived == true) {
                 AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;
                 menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
                int index = menuInfo.position;
                removeItem(index);
                confirmationReceived = false;
                return true;
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .create();
return myRemovalDialogBox;
}
```

Comment: then pass the item to the  the function.. Like 
AskRemoveConfirm(MenuItem item)

Comment: and then pass AlertDialog diaBox = AskRemoveConfirm(item);